# MonoGame - Model not rendering properly

Tags: c#, 3d, monogame, models

I'm trying to render a model made in Blender. I export it to .fbx and import it in the content pipeline, load and draw it, but it displays like this:

[image]

And this is what it looks like in Blender:

[image]

Code that draws the model:

```
foreach (ModelMesh modelMesh in model.Meshes)
{
    foreach (BasicEffect basicEffect in modelMesh.Effects)
    {
        basicEffect.EnableDefaultLighting();
        basicEffect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
        basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
        basicEffect.View = camera.ViewMatrix;
        basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(width / height, MathHelper.PiOver2, 0.1f, 100f);
    }

    modelMesh.Draw();
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the model?

Comment: Looks like you're not using the depth buffer — either not reading it, or not writing to it.

Comment: I don't know what that is. Is that in MonoGame or Blender?

Comment: Did you search the term to find out? Don't underestimate your ability to find your own answers! [This previous user experienced similar symptoms due to how they configured their camera](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21639/39518) — putting the near plane too close to the camera and the far plane too far, so there wasn't enough depth resolution to correctly sort scene fragments at typical view distances.

Comment: Yeah, I was having a look and I saw some stuff about the near and far clip planes and now I understand them even less. Setting the near to 1 didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you should show us your current settings then.

Comment: If by settings you mean the perspective field of view parameters, they're in the code.

Comment: Ah whoops, I'm on mobile so that bit was cropped out. Apologies for the redundancy